# Octopus string variables that contain whitespace

Tags: octopus-deploy

We have a Project variable that is the path to install our package.
As you can see below, the path contains a whitespace character.

The deployment fails with “Invalid characters in string” when I use double quotes.
I tried single-quotes and that produced an incorrect substitution.
Without any quoting, the value substituted is C:\Program Files.

Variable Name:  Windows.Services.Path

Value:          C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder

Answer (score 0):

you can use "custom installation directory Feature" in "Deploy Package Step" to copy your files in specific path using variable. See the below image.

custom installation directory Feature allows you to deploy package in path which contains space.

[image]